# How to "trace"/"extrude"/"sweep" an animated 3d mesh?

Tags: modeling, modifiers, geometry, extrude

Given an arbitrarily animated 3d mesh, is it possible to generate a new object such that this new object is the interpolated boolean sum of all frames of the animated target object?

I can somewhat do this in a python script, but the boolean union starts to degrade and loose surfaces over iterations. Also, it's hard to achieve a smooth result, as each iteration takes more time since there are more surfaces to union with.

The [`Screw Modifier`](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/generate/screw.html) has the spirit of what I'm trying to do, if the animation was a linear translation and rotation along a single axis. Is these a similar modifier or tool where you can specify a path and orientation?

[image: Screw modifier generation]

[`BTracer`](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/addons/add_curve/btracer.html) `Mesh Follow` mode also has the spirit of what I'm looking for, except it only constructs curves. Below you can see the the target 3d mesh (cube) being animated, and `BTracer` creating 8 curves following the trace of the cube's 8 vertices. What I'm looking for is a generated solid which would fill the outlines of these curves.

[image: BTracer output]

I realise I could take the curves from the `BTracer` process and generate faces between them, but for more complex objects this would get very tedious.

Is there a process or tool I can use to generate the geometry I'm looking for?

Comment: Somewhat related https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/122315/15543  https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/122232/15543

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/79445/using-boolean-modifiers-and-shape-keys-in-animation/79449#79449