# Is there a way to simulate the drilling process in blender without using FEA (finite element analysis)?

Tags: modeling, animation, rigid-body-simulation

so I'm trying to create a commercial AD for a drill bit made of tungsten carbide, this drill bit is made for cutting concrete walls especially when it comes to passing through rebars. I've made some research and find about LS-DYNA which is used in engineering in order to simulate problems and process, that involves physics and a lot of concepts. The thing is I've done a simulation and it takes 13 DAYS to only simulate 10 seconds of the drilling process in LS-DYNA.

Can someone enlighten me about how to simulate without burning my computer?

[image: LSDYNA -Prepost drillbit]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/79445/using-boolean-modifiers-and-shape-keys-in-animation/79449

Comment: Yes, thanks for the help, I used live boolean modifiers to achieve that goal.

Answer (score 0):

Using mesh master tools add-on you can achieve the drilling process simulation without burning your PC. Thanks to Duarte Darrajota Ramos and Emir, for the ideas.