# Is There a way to Apply Visual Geometry to Mesh with Geometry Nodes?

Tags: animation

I am wondering is there is a way to apply the geometry of an object every frame using geometry nodes. I am attempting to make a lathe animation, but I need the Boolean of the cutting tool to stay in place after each frame. If there is a way to apply the geometry of the mesh using geometry nodes, or have something that does the same thing, I would greatly appreciate any responses. I am still a bit of a noob to geometry nodes, so sorry if it's really obvious.
Thanks

Comment: it depends what you want to do....(as usual). Normally a lathe is moving so fast, you will only see the "result", the normal human eye won't see the "little step" each rotation has, so you could just use a "normal" boolean modifier and e.g. make the cutter just bigger or smaller

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/79445/using-boolean-modifiers-and-shape-keys-in-animation/79449#79449

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i just show the "principle" how it works - of course you can animate and do the same things with geometry nodes.

The principle is: just "hide" the cutter (and add a "real" cutter instead) and then just animate the cutter:

So here on the left side is the object which should be cut (box):

[image]

the cylinder is the cutter (which you should hide). Then give the box a boolean modifier with the cutter as object and move the cylinder like this:

[image]

then hide the cutter:

[image]

of course you can add more cutters, i added this:

[image]

and this:

[image]

added them to the boolean modifiers (you could also work with a collection):

[image]

result:

[image]

of course you should then animate the "real" cutters to it so that it looks real...and maybe some particles flying around for the shavings.

and here the same principle just with GN setup:

[image]

result:

[image]

Comment: This works for simple examples, however, I'm not sure it will for complex shapes. In my case, I will have the tool following an organic path that might not be possible with cutters.

Comment: If that is the case you should improve your question so that others don’t waste their time like I did because of your imprecise question. Thanks.