Animated Boolean
I'm relatively new to Blender and trying to put together a simple little animation which in a simplistic way goes as follows.
A pre drilled hole is reamed to size so that the hole is one size before the reamer goes through and I want to see the material get removed in an "accurate way".
Currently I can only get the  material to be removed by the Boolean modifier in the locations where the reamer currently is. Not where it has already been as well.
I'd be happy to provide more info, but if anyone could point me in the right direction that'd be great. Additionally the "accurate" setting under boolean hardly seems to work, as every other frame it makes my workpiece completely disappear from the viewport and render, so instead I'm just using "fast" for now.
Another important aspect is that reamers have flutes of sorts and so it spins removing only a portion of that cross section at a time.



Maybe use a different object than the reamer on the Boolean modifier ? And are you meshes manifold ? It will be hard to debug your issue without seeing any details or settings.

My meshes are somewhat subpar, they are real products pulled from cnc grinders that were not originally intended for 3d modeling. However it's necessary to use them in order to maintain product accurate geometry. I will try to upload a blend file in a minute.

Part of the goal here is to have the material removed in the same way that a real reamer would cut through steel. Sort of peeling it away in four separate radial locations (1 for each flute). So I can't see any real benefit in using another object, unless I'm misunderstanding you here.

https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/79445/using-boolean-modifiers-and-shape-keys-in-animation/

@DuarteFarrajotaRamos I, have already achieved this with an invisible cylinder that removes material level with the bottom of the reamer. However I would like to make it more in depth so that as the tool spins about its z axis, material is radially removed as well behind it. I have seen no information on how to accomplish this as it seems rather labor intensive.

Maybe boolean with an animated object with shape morphing changes. Alternatively perhaps using two booleans, one with the dynamic part of the changes, other responsible for "holding the shape" of the drilled parts
